# R subsetting by partially matching row name

Tags: r, regex, subset

I have a tab delimited file:

```
row.names c1 c2 c3
AF3 0 2 4
BN4 9 1 2 
AF2 8 7 1
BN8 4 6 8
```

And I want to select only the rows with row names beginning with BN4, output would be like:

```
row.names c1 c2 c3
BN4 9 1 2 
BN8 4 6 8
```

I know how I would solve the problem if I knew the exact row names in a vector...

```
df[row.names(df) %in% c('BN4','BN8'), ]
```

But how would I solve the problem by finding and subsetting on the rows that start with 'BN'?

Comment: I assume that "names beginning with **BN4**" is a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `grep` to find those rows whose names start with "BN".

Using `x` for the object instead of `df` (`df` is a function in R):

```
x[grep("^BN", row.names(x)),]
##     c1 c2 c3
## BN4  9  1  2
## BN8  4  6  8
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `slice()` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% slice(grep("^BN", row.names(.)))
```

Which gives:

```
#  c1 c2 c3
#1  9  1  2
#2  4  6  8
```

Here, row names are silently dropped. To preserve them, you can convert to an explicit variable by using `add_rownames()`:

```
df %>% add_rownames() %>% slice(grep("^BN", rowname))
```

or using `filter()`:

```
df %>% add_rownames() %>% filter(grepl("^BN", rowname))
```

You get:

```
#  rowname c1 c2 c3
#1     BN4  9  1  2
#2     BN8  4  6  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions with `grepl`

```
df[grepl("BN\\d{1}", row.names(df), ]
```

If you would prefer functions that are a little more descriptive, you can do the same thing with the `stringr` package

```
df[str_detect(row.names(df), "BN\\d{1}"), ]
```

The catch is that these calls will pick up any rows that have a three character match of BN[digit] anywhere in the string.  Something like XYBN9L would get picked up.

Comment: How would one fix that "catch"?

Comment: If you really need it to be just the first two characters, you could try `substr(row.names(df), 1, 2) == "BN"`.  `substr` will pull only the first two letters from the row name.  I'm sure there's a regular expression that will look at only the first two letters, but that I struggle with regular expressions beyond the basics.